# Socket.io, connect to socket inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, socket.io

My app is using websocket with Socket.io library. On the fronted, I open a connection to a backend socket like this :

```
io.connect(window.location.origin)
```

Everything is working fine when my backend is running on my computer. But when I run it inside a docker container, I get this error on my client:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Invalid frame header
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that I must make the socket listen on '0.0.0.0'